# How do I add seconds to a timestamp of a start date so that I can get an estimated end date?

Tags: sql, timestamp

I have a Task object with a start_time and an estimated time in seconds. The start_time is stored in the database as a  MYSQL DATETIME and the estimated time is stored as seconds. I would like to add the seconds to the start_time to get an estimated finish date.

Comment: As you're talking about the MySQL datatype, I preseume you desire to do this in SQL.  As such, I'd recommend not using th java and jdbc tags.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

There is a lot in the link Neville gave, but cutting slightly to the chase...

```
my_date_time + INTERVAL xx SECOND
```

I think it is more *correct* to use DATE_ADD(), but as far as I know there is no performance difference.