# Mysql query that will return free slots between timestamps in database

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I have three columns in a database - event_id, timestamp and length_of_event_in_seconds.
Beginning of each event has some timestamp, and now I want to produce the query that will insert new event (that lasts length_of_event_in_seconds) in a free time between some timestamps - as soon as there's 'length_in_seconds' free spot for that. Can someone help me with that?

Comment: You said it; "between" http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-between - You almost answered your own question.

Comment: Thanks, I just have a problem with finding the correct values that I can use in between query, I don't have any idea how could I check whether the free slot is long enough for storing new event

Comment: Query and use a conditional statement. `if/else`

Comment: Could you help me with constructing such query?

Answer (score 0):

Using the advice gathered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5325854/how-do-i-add-seconds-to-a-timestamp-of-a-start-date-so-that-i-can-get-an-estimat):

```
select * 
from table 
where ts_begin >= 'begin-boundary-time' 
    and ts_begin + interval length_of_event_in_seconds seconds <= 'end-boundary-time'
```

Comment: This actually won't work properly. It will only find events that begin after and end before the searched timespan. It wouldn't include events that partially overlap or completely encompass the searched timespan. To find overlap you need to swap the begin and end "boundary times". Something like `ts_begin <= 'end-boundary-time' and ts_end >= 'begin-boundary-time'`. This will give you a list of overlapping events. If zero rows are returned, then there is no overlap.

Comment: Actually, OP is looking for the inverse of the search -- where is there free time between events.  I think he was getting hung up on how to write the where clause to determine times that are considered "free".  Even if this doesn't solve the problem as written (which it can't since the OP post is vague on the structure) it should give him a push in the right direction on the where clause.

Comment: Yes, if the table had rows with "free time". However, it is much more likely that there are rows with events and anytime an event is not scheduled is assumed to be free.

Comment: Hey Guys, I just assume that using that logic that PaulProgrammer suggested it will be impossible to add overlapping events, and that's actually my goal - to have everything in order without overlapping. In that case - will the code suggested by Paul be sufficient?

Comment: @randomuser2 His code will only find events as I described above. It will not find partial overlapping events or events that completely encompass the described timeframe. If you swap the begin/end "boundary time" then it will return all events that occur during that time. If there are zero, nothing overlaps. If there any rows, these overlap and you can further decide if the overlap should occur. Maybe a column saying co-use/exclusive event or a limit on how many events can take place at a time.

Comment: Ok, I just thought about it once again - the query suggested above will return me the events between two dates, but it will not tell me where can I insert the data... Could you help me with constructing INSERT query based on that select above?